# How to use asm procedure and take return value in C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, toolchain

i've got a gcc version 2.95.2 19991024 (release) toolchain and now i need to use an Assembly function that is in a file positioned in the same folder of the makefile.

I've tried tons of ways to put that file in my toolchain, with no luck.

Basically i declare that in ASM:

```
.globl  util_MyFunc
util_MyFunc: 
...
```

And in the main void of C file:

```
extern void util_MyFunc();
int main(void) {  
 util_MyFunc();
...
```

When i compile i got the error related to not recognized:

```
/cygdrive/c/MyDev/tmp/main.o(.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to `util_MyFunc'
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

i've tried to use following to generate the ".o" file from the asm file

```
C:\MyDev>gcc -c test.asm -o test.o
```

It results:

```
gcc: utils.asm: linker input file unused since linking not done
```

or:

```
C:\MyDev>gcc test.asm -o test.o
```

but...:

```
ld: cannot open crt0.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you run gcc on your assembly file?

Comment: You really should **update your compiler**. `gcc-2.95` is from the *previous century* and is well known to be *buggy*, *not good at optimizing*, and *non-standard compliant*. Current [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is 4.9.2 since october 2014; you can compile it as a cross-compiler. Using GCC 2.95 is a *mistake*.

Comment: see edit please. 
If i'm using that old gcc there's a reason. I would try anyway to upgrade, but anyway...can somebody point to the right direction about my problem?

Comment: I don't see any explanation (even after your edit) about using GCC 2.95. It is so buggy and old that there is no reason to use it (except if you want to become an expert in compiler history). You'll be hurt by other issues.

Comment: Basile...do you mind if i ask u something behind the scenes?
Can u share your email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical extension for assembly files that gcc expects is `.s`. You should use that (or assemble using `as` directly). Also possibly put the `-o test.o` before the input file name. Finally, you will need libc development files if you want to use libc. Otherwise use `-nostdlib` switch.

You should try: `gcc -o test main.c utils.s`

Comment: yeah it worked, but it gaves me now a tons of Assembler errors...but the answer was right so green checked!